# getting name error for already defined list objects.any possible help should be appreciated,

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

guys don't know why getting name error for already defined object,trying to created a text based black jack game  but getting error for already defined list(person and dealer ),when i try to run startGame function(actually this function give two random cards to both dealer and person and add both those value separately)

**input**

```
def rand():
    king=10
    jack=10
    queen=10
    one=2
    two=3
    three=4
    four=5
    five=6
    six=7
    seven=8
    eight=9
    nine=10
    import random
    return random.choice([king,queen,jack,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,])

class black():
    person=[]
    dealer=[]
    def __init__(self,rando):
        self.rando=rando
        
    def StartingGame(self):
        import math

        person.append(rand())
        person.append(rand())
        dealer.append(rand())
        dealer.append(rand())
        return math.fsum(person),math.fsum(dealer)
```

**output**

```
tt=black(rand())
tt.StartingGame()

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-adf1a6aa555c> in <module>
----> 1 tt.StartingGame()

<ipython-input-1-ad7bd57d22e4> in StartingGame(self)
     26         import math
     27 
---> 28         person.append(rand())
     29         person.append(rand())
     30         dealer.append(rand())

NameError: name 'person' is not defined
```

Comment: You need `self.person`

Comment: And you also ought to have instance variables which are set in `__init__`. Don't have mutable objects as class variables or you will modify them for all instances, which is probably not what you want.  So basically, in `__init__` set `self.person=[]` and then in `StartingGame` do `self.person.append(....)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `self.person`, because `class` scope is not included in LEGB-rule.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the class as it stands in the question.

One is a simple issue of scope: class is not a scope which is searched when resolving names, so you need to use `self.person` and not just `person`.

The other issue is that you are using mutable objects (here lists) as class variables.  You will find if you do that that other instances of the same class will share the same objects for these variables, which is probably not what you want.  Instead, use instance variables, initialising them inside `__init__`:

```
import math

# ...

class Black():

    def __init__(self, rando):
        self.rando = rando
        self.person = []
        self.dealer = []
        
    def starting_game(self):
        self.person.append(rand())
        self.person.append(rand())
        self.dealer.append(rand())
        self.dealer.append(rand())
        return math.fsum(person), math.fsum(dealer)
```

Note also other corrections:

- naming convention: initial capital for class, lower case (with underscore where needed rather than CamelCase) for the method
- (usually) put your import at the top, not inside the function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling function local variable `person` but not `black` class property. `dealer` variable also give you same error in the `StartingGame` function. If you want to call class property `person` and `dealer` you have to call it by function `self` variable. Example `self.person` `self.dealer`.